# How to balance my image (and text) inside div and both must remains responsive

Tags: html, css, google-web-designer

I am a super beginner in HTML and CSS. It was actually aligned and balanced until I put text inside each three divs and photos become like this, unbalanced even I use the same width and height:

[image]

**These are the codes:**

```css
#wrapper{
 display:flex;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: space-around;
 }
 
 .party{
 display:inline-flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 2%;
 
 }
 
 .party img{
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 0.3%;
 margin: 2%;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 }
 input[type = button] {
 background-color: black;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 color: white;
 margin: 2px 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class = "party">
<img src = "Images/birthday_1.jpg">
<h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;">Party Events</h3>
<p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;"> Want flower decoration for your birthday, ceremonies, baby showers and any party events? Consult to our florist now!</p>
<input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
</div>
<div class ="party">
<img src = "Images/wedding_1.jpg">
<h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;"> Wedding Events </h3>
<p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;">We offer free consultation for a bride-to-be. Call our store to make an appointment on <b>+64 85459 3943</b></p>
<input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
</div>
<div class = "party">
<img src = "Images/sympathy.jpg">
<h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;">Sympathy</h3>
<center><p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;"> Fresh flowers that express heartfelt thoughts and sincere condolences. Talk to our dedicated team by phone or come in to meet with our flourist in a private consultation.</p></center>
<input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
</div>
</div>
```

**This is my ideal result:**

[image]

**
What should I do? Any recommendations?**

Comment: Do you want the images distorted?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Yeah that would do as long as it looks like the ideal result below the image i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#wrapper{
    display:flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.party{
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 33.33%;
}
.party-image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border: solid black 2px;
    padding: 0.3%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    margin: 2%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.party img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
}
input[type = button] {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    margin: 2px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class = "party">
        <div class="party-image-wrapper">
            <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg">
        </div>
        <h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;">Party Events</h3>
        <p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;"> Want flower decoration for your birthday, ceremonies, baby showers and any party events? Consult to our florist now!</p>
        <input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
    </div>
    <div class ="party">
        <div class="party-image-wrapper">
            <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/1200px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg">
        </div>
        <h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;"> Wedding Events </h3>
        <p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;">We offer free consultation for a bride-to-be. Call our store to make an appointment on <b>+64 85459 3943</b></p>
        <input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
    </div>
    <div class = "party">
        <div class="party-image-wrapper">
            <img src = "https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=49ed3252c0b2ffb49cf8b508892e452d">
        </div>
        <h3 style = "font-size: 2vw;">Sympathy</h3>
        <center>
            <p style = "font-size: 1.5vw;"> Fresh flowers that express heartfelt thoughts and sincere condolences. Talk to our dedicated team by phone or come in to meet with our flourist in a private consultation.</p>
        </center>
        <input type = "button" value = " Shop Now "/>
    </div>
</div>
```

When using flex to put elements on the same row the default behavior is for the elements to adapt to their content's width. To fix this you can simply set a width of each element, I chose 33.33% because we have 3 elements, so 100 / 3 = 33.33.

As for the images, there's a trick to lock them to a responsive square regardless of the image size or ratio, you need to put the image into a container, set the container's height to 0 and the padding-top (or bottom) to 100%, since the percentage is based on it's width it will make the container a perfect square.

Once you have that square you can use position: absolute; on the image itself to position it relative to the container, and then use object-fit: cover, which basically tells the browser to always fill the container with a given element. it's a bit complicated but I hope it makes sense, you said you're still a beginner so don't worry if it's not super clear for now, you'll get to it eventually. If you have other questions drop them in the comments

Comment: Thanks very much; it's working great! It doesn't look like the ideal result, but the images are perfectly balanced. Yes, I will try to do that image thing about what you recommended to me. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason that the boxes resize like that is that they are part of a flexbox layout, and the default is for them to grow/shrink with their contents. There are ways to adjust this, but in your case, it sounds like you want all 3 boxes to have an equal width.

If you know you will only have 3 `party` boxes, then don't rely on flexbox for the widths, and just do this:

```
.party {
    display:inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 33.33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you'd prefer to keep the flexbox, you can instead use `flex-basis: 33.33%` instead of `width: 33.33%`.